# Input fields are not getting disabled after clicking on back button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Once the form is opened all the input fields and select fields are in disabled mode after clicking on edit button the fields will be in editable format.

Once i click on edit button the text is changing to Back button and once i click on back button the text will be edit button but the problem is once i click on back button the text is changing to edit successfully but the fields also should change from editable mode to disable mode.

```js
$('input').attr('disabled', true);                
$('.editbutton').on('click', function(e) {               e.preventDefault();                 
  $('input').attr('disabled', false);                
})                
$('select').attr('disabled', true);                
$('.editbutton').on('click', function(e) {                e.preventDefault();                 
  $('select').attr('disabled', false);
})

function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
  if (btn.value == "Edit") {
    btn.value = "Back";                  
    btn.innerHTML = "Back";
  }
  else {
    btn.value = "Edit";                  
    btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="myButton"  onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default editbutton" value="Edit">Edit</button>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" value="Doctor" class="form-control validate">          
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" value="p" class="form-control validate">          
</div>              
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" value="doctor@gmail.com" class="form-control validate">          
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone-number" value="1234567890" class="form-control validate">          
</div>              
<div class="md-form col-md-2">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="isverified">Is Verified?</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="verified" checked> </div>     
<button class="btn btn-default">Update Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try using [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove the attribute you want:

```js
$('input').attr('disabled', true);    
$('select').attr('disabled', true);  
$('#myButton').on('click', function(e) {                      
  e.preventDefault();  
  if($('input').attr('disabled')){
    $('input').removeAttr('disabled');    
    $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
    this.textContent = "Back";
  }
  else{
    $('input').attr('disabled', true);    
    $('select').attr('disabled', true);
    this.textContent = "Edit";
  }                                                            
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="myButton" class="btn btn-default editbutton" value="Edit">Edit</button>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" value="Doctor" class="form-control validate">          
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" value="p" class="form-control validate">          
</div>                                                      
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" value="doctor@gmail.com" class="form-control validate">          
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone-number" value="1234567890" class="form-control validate">          
</div>                                                      
<div class="md-form col-md-2">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="isverified">Is Verified?</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="verified" checked> </div>                  
<button class="btn btn-default">Update Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check your <kbd>button</kbd> text and  enable , disable based on this.

```js
$('input').attr('disabled', true);
$('select').attr('disabled', true);
$('.editbutton').on('click', function(e) {

  let txt = $(this).text();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (txt == "Edit") {
    $('input').attr('disabled', true);
    $('select').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('input').attr('disabled', false);
    $('select').attr('disabled', false);

  }
})


function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
  if (btn.value == "Edit") {
    btn.value = "Back";
    btn.innerHTML = "Back";
  } else {
    btn.value = "Edit";
    btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default editbutton" value="Edit">Edit</button>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" value="Doctor" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" value="p" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" value="doctor@gmail.com" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone-number" value="1234567890" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-2">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="isverified">Is Verified?</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="verified" checked>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default">Update Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
    if (btn.value == "Edit") {
      btn.value = "Back";
      btn.innerHTML = "Back";
      enableDisable(true)
    } else {
      btn.value = "Edit";
      btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
      enableDisable(false)
    }
  }

  function enableDisable(enable) {
    if (enable) {
      $('input').attr('disabled', false);

    } else {
      $('input').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially attaching three click event listeners to element's using the editbutton class. The onclick inside the html code is enough tough.

So simply deactivate your input field initially and enable/disable it inside the callback function myFunction().

Like this:

```js
$('input').attr('disabled', true); 
function myFunction() {

    var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
    if (btn.value == "Edit") {
    btn.value = "Back";                                                                  
   btn.innerHTML = "Back";$('input').attr('disabled', false); 
    }
    else {
    btn.value = "Edit";                                                                  
    btn.innerHTML = "Edit";$('input').attr('disabled', true); 
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default editbutton" value="Edit">Edit</button>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" value="Doctor" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" value="p" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" value="doctor@gmail.com" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone-number" value="1234567890" class="form-control validate">
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-2">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="isverified">Is Verified?</label><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="verified" checked>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default">Update Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not set it up properly. This should work. Also remove call to myFunction()

```
<script>
// Disable all elements.
$('input').attr('disabled', true);

// Set up onClickListener 
$('.editbutton').on('click', (e) => {
    var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
    if (btn.value == "Edit") {
        $('input').attr('disabled', false);
        btn.value = "Back";                                                                  
        btn.innerHTML = "Back";
    } else {
        $('input').attr('disabled', true);
        btn.value = "Edit";                                                                  
        btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this code `$('input').attr('disabled', false);` on the conditional part of your function, false if button value is edit else true.

```js
$('input').attr('disabled', true);                                                                                                   
 $('select').attr('disabled', true);                                                             
 $('.editbutton').on('click', function(e) {                                                              
 e.preventDefault();                                                                 
 $('select').attr('disabled', false);
  })

function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
  if (btn.value == "Edit") {
    btn.value = "Back";                                                             
    btn.innerHTML = "Back";
    $('input').attr('disabled', false);    
  } else {
    btn.value = "Edit";                                            
    btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
    $('input').attr('disabled', true);  
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="myButton"  onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default editbutton" value="Edit">Edit</button>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="first-name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="first-name" value="Doctor" class="form-control validate">          
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="last-name" value="p" class="form-control validate">          
</div>                                                      
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" value="doctor@gmail.com" class="form-control validate">          
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-5">
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" id="phone-number" value="1234567890" class="form-control validate">          
</div>                                                      
<div class="md-form col-md-2">
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="isverified">Is Verified?</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="verified" checked>                
</div>                  
<button class="btn btn-default">Update Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = $('input');
const button = $('.editbutton');

input.attr('disabled', true);

button.on('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.currentTarget;

    let value = target.value;

    if(target.value === 'Edit') {
        input.attr('disabled', false);
        target.value = 'Back'

    } else {
        input.attr('disabled', true);
        target.value = 'Edit'
    }

    target.innerHTML = target.value;
});
```

And remove this `onclick="myFunction()"` as you don't need it.

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/muzikant/0w3xgrq7/8/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `onclick="myFunction"` in the button element. You are adding an event listener via jquery, so you can just use that.

```
$('input').attr('disabled', true);  
$('.editbutton').on('click', function(e) {                                                              
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunction();
}
```

Then change myFunction to change the disable attribute as you click.

```
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
if (btn.value == "Edit") {
    $('input').attr('disabled', false);
    btn.value = "Back";                                                                  
    btn.innerHTML = "Back";
}
else {
    $('input').attr('disabled', true);
    btn.value = "Edit";                                                                  
    btn.innerHTML = "Edit";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `prop` method instead of `attr` method.

Comment: This answer may be better suited as a comment.